# Change from onclick to onload

Tags: javascript, image, scroll

I would like to animate an image to scroll across the page. I currently have an onClick version of this below but would like it to automatically run on page load.

Ive tried adding onload='moveRight()' in the body tag but i get an error:

'cannot read property type of 'null''

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var imgObj = null;
    var animate ;
    function init(){
       imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
       imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
       imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
    }
    function moveRight(){
       imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 1 + 'px';
       animate = setTimeout(moveRight,400); // call moveRight in 400msec
    }
    function stop(){
       clearTimeout(animate);
       imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
    }
    window.onload =init;
    //-->
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>

   <head>

     <title>JavaScript</title>

   </head>

 <body>

  <form>
   <img id="myImage" src="/images/html.gif" />
    <p>Click the buttons below to handle animation</p>
     <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="moveRight();" />
     <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stop();" />
  </form>

 </body>

</html>
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another function to call `init` and `moveRight` on onload.Modify your code as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var imgObj = null;
    var animate;
    function init() {
        imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
        imgObj.style.position = 'relative';
        imgObj.style.left = '0px';
    }
    function moveRight() {
        imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 1 + 'px';
        animate = setTimeout(moveRight, 400); // call moveRight in 400msec
    }
    function stop() {
        clearTimeout(animate);
        imgObj.style.left = '0px';
    }
    function InitMove() {
        init();
        moveRight();
    }
    window.onload = InitMove;

</script>
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you :).

How come it wasn't allowing me to add a 'window.onload=moveRight;' to the end of the code? In theory this asks the code to carry out the same action as your function.